# Why don't spacy transformer models do NER for non-english models?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-transformers

Why is it that spacy transformer models for languages like spanish (`es_dep_news_trf`) don't do named entity recognition.

However, for english (`en_core_web_trf`) it does.

In code:

```
import spacy    
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
doc=nlp("my name is John Smith and I work at Apple and I like visiting the Eiffel Tower")
print(doc.ents)
(John Smith, Apple, the Eiffel Tower)
    
nlp=spacy.load("es_dep_news_trf")
doc=nlp("mi nombre es John Smith y trabajo en Apple y me gusta visitar la Torre Eiffel")
print(doc.ents)
()
```

Why doesn't spanish extract entities but english does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the available training data. `ner` is only included for the `trf` models if the training data has NER annotation on the exact same data as for tagging and parsing.

Training `trf` models on partial annotation does not work well in practice and an independent NER component (as in the CNN pipelines) would mean including an additional `transformer` component in the pipeline, which would make the pipeline a lot larger and slower.

Answer (score 1):

The spaCy models vary with regards to which NLP features they provide - this is just a result of how the respective authors created/trained them. I.e., https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_trf lists "ner" in its components, but https://spacy.io/models/es#es_dep_news_trf does not.

The Spanish https://spacy.io/models/es#es_core_news_lg (as well the two smaller variants) does list "ner" in its components, so they show named entities:

```
>>> import spacy  
>>> nlp=spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")
>>> doc=nlp("mi nombre es John Smith y trabajo en Apple y me gusta visitar la Torre Eiffel")
>>> print(doc.ents)
(John Smith, Apple, Torre Eiffel)
```